# Abantecart jquery onebyone

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a abantecart script that I am porting a youtube gallery script into, see here http://gsamin.org/a/ The youtube gallery script works fine, BUT the abantecart has a text banner that slides different banners/text, at the top, that works fine until I load/turn on the gallery script, then the error below is what shows as it hits/play up to the error, it "snags" right before moving to the next slide. 
the banner works fine if the youtube gallery script is not on, it stops when the gallery is on. all files are calledable from the source.

how do I fix this, fixing or changing the gallery script to run along with the banner would be great,in other words I'd much rather change the youtube script than the abantecart banner script.

thanks for any help.

```
jquery.min.js:4 [Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread 
is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's 
experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.
send @ jquery.min.js:4
ajax @ jquery.min.js:4
update_cart @ (index):57
(anonymous) @ (index):94
dispatch @ jquery-1.12.4.min.js:3
r.handle @ jquery-1.12.4.min.js:3
load (async)
add @ jquery-1.12.4.min.js:3
e.event.add @ jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js:2
(anonymous) @ jquery-1.12.4.min.js:3
each @ jquery-1.12.4.min.js:2
each @ jquery-1.12.4.min.js:2
sa @ jquery-1.12.4.min.js:3
on @ jquery-1.12.4.min.js:3
(anonymous) @ (index):93
jquery.carouFredSel.min.js:15 carouFredSel: No element found for 
"#brandcarousal".
jquery.onebyone.min.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'msie' of 
undefined
at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (jquery.onebyone.min.js:1)
at HTMLDivElement.d.complete (jquery.min.js:4)
at j (jquery.min.js:2)
at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
at i (jquery.min.js:4)
at m.fx.tick (jquery.min.js:4)
(anonymous) @ jquery.onebyone.min.js:1
d.complete @ jquery.min.js:4
j @ jquery.min.js:2
fireWith @ jquery.min.js:2
i @ jquery.min.js:4
m.fx.tick @ jquery.min.js:4
setInterval (async)
m.fx.start @ jquery.min.js:4
m.fx.timer @ jquery.min.js:4
kc @ jquery.min.js:4
g @ jquery.min.js:4
dequeue @ jquery.min.js:3
(anonymous) @ jquery.min.js:3
each @ jquery.min.js:2
each @ jquery.min.js:2
queue @ jquery.min.js:3
animate @ jquery.min.js:4
s @ jquery.onebyone.min.js:1
p @ jquery.onebyone.min.js:1
(anonymous) @ jquery.onebyone.min.js:1
setInterval (async)
d @ jquery.onebyone.min.js:1
(anonymous) @ jquery.onebyone.min.js:1
dequeue @ jquery.min.js:3
g @ jquery.min.js:3
setTimeout (async)
(anonymous) @ jquery.min.js:4
dequeue @ jquery.min.js:3
d.complete @ jquery.min.js:4
j @ jquery.min.js:2
fireWith @ jquery.min.js:2
i @ jquery.min.js:4
m.fx.tick @ jquery.min.js:4
setInterval (async)
m.fx.start @ jquery.min.js:4
m.fx.timer @ jquery.min.js:4
kc @ jquery.min.js:4
g @ jquery.min.js:4
dequeue @ jquery.min.js:3
(anonymous) @ jquery.min.js:3
each @ jquery.min.js:2
each @ jquery.min.js:2
queue @ jquery.min.js:3
animate @ jquery.min.js:4
s @ jquery.onebyone.min.js:1
c.fn.oneByOne @ jquery.onebyone.min.js:1
(anonymous) @ custom.js:4
j @ jquery.min.js:2
add @ jquery.min.js:2
m.fn.ready @ jquery.min.js:2
m.fn.init @ jquery.min.js:2
m @ jquery.min.js:2
(anonymous) @ custom.js:2
dispatch @ jquery.min.js:3
r.handle @ jquery.min.js:3
load (async)
add @ jquery.min.js:3
(anonymous) @ jquery.min.js:3
each @ jquery.min.js:2
each @ jquery.min.js:2
on @ jquery.min.js:3
(anonymous) @ bootstrap.min.js:6
(anonymous) @ bootstrap.min.js:6
```

Comment: I solved this thanks